# Editing database metadata

Tags: sql

I am curious about the link between actual database commands and deleting rows from database metadata.

For example, is the following command...

`drop table products`

... the same as this one?

`delete from information_schema.tables where table_name='products'` (SQL CE)

The above commands is for `SQL Server Compact` but the question most likely remains valid across all database platforms. Just curious as to if the second command actually does the same job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not.

First, the `information_schema` tables are generally views on underlying tables.  So, even if you *could* delete a row from them, you really couldn't.

Second, dropping a table is way more than deleting just the table.  You have to delete the column definitions, the constraints, the indexes, and the triggers.  You also have to remove all the pages associated with the table, and free any in-memory copies in the page-cache.  And there's probably a bunch of other work going on too.

It sounds like you want to learn more about how databases really work.  I encourage you to read documentation available on-line and to seek out good books about database software.